# Intellij: Use Google Play Services AAR in a mavenized project

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to use Google Play Services 4.0.3 AAR together with IntelliJ 13 (133.193) 
I used install-file like this:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=$ANDROID_HOME/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/4.0.30/play-services-4.0.30.aar  -DgroupId=com.google.android.gms -DartifactId=play-services -Dversion=4.0.30 -Dpackaging=aar`

And added dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.30</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

When running `mvn install` from the CLI it seems to be compiling just fine, however IntelliJ fails to include the package and provide inspections/autocomplete for it, and all symbols show error/not recognized.
The package DOES show on the Maven panel under 'dependencies', but does not show in the Project panel under External Libraries.

Using android-maven-plugin 3.8.1

Comment: just in case - have you tried Android Studio?

Comment: I'm not sure that idea supports new Android library files format. But most probably gradle plugin does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AAR support is now available in [IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `android-maven-plugin` into my `pom.xml` (note that you will need to import maven into your project after adding these sections):

```
<project>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.2</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```